# Помогите! Почему моего сайта нет по запросу вообще?

Tags: seo

Мой сайт - http://artemandrosov.ru , почему когда набираешь "обучение программированию", то моего сайта даже на 1000 месте нету? Спасибо.

Comment: Ключевые слова Пушкин будет прописывать? SEO-продвижением тоже он будет заниматься?

Comment: Потому что существует тысяча сайтов с обучением программированию, которые более круты чем ваш сайт?

Comment: В смысле? У меня ведь и в title и в description и в h1 ключ есть..

Comment: У другой тысячи сайтов тоже есть)

Comment: Но если бы он не входил просто в 1к, но его вообще нет

Comment: Можно , пожалуйста, рекомендации что поменять

Comment: @АндросовАртём да ну, вы просмотрели все 35 700 000 результатов?

Comment: Есть специальные сайты, которые это все просматривают

Comment: https://www.seogadget.ru/serppos

Comment: Ну там написано «Глубина анализа результатов поиска - первые 50 позиций.»

Comment: А что поменять? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста!

Comment: Если вы обучаете разработке, то гуглить уж явно умеете.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы по SEO не имеют нормального технического обоснования, основаны на мнении. Спрашивайте на searchengines.guru

Answer (score 3):

Если ввести в гугл запрос `site:http://artemandrosov.ru/`, то там целых 3 страницы с результатами, так что твоё утверждение, что сайта там нет неверно. А первой ссылкой идёт информация для разработчика сайта, которую не помешало бы прочитать.

Но вообще, я сильно смоневаюсь, что этому сайту место в топе. Часть страниц не готова, оформление сомнительно, а примеры кода вообще не отформатированы.